# How to style MUI X Charts xy axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-x, mui-x-charts

I'm working with sample code from MUI X Charts Styling page and am trying to figure out how to change the color of the xy axis and numbers. I've read through the documentation [here](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/styling/) for Javascript but have only learned how to change the color of the data itself. It seems like it's possible to change the axes since the axes do change color on the mui website when switching from dark mode to light mode but I've tried using sx for styling along with a few other methods to no avail.

Lines 28-36 is my attempt to apply color to the axes but they don't actually do anything. I was hoping to have changed the colors to blue as well as the numbers on the axes.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { LineChart } from "@mui/x-charts/LineChart";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import ToggleButton from "@mui/material/ToggleButton";
import ToggleButtonGroup from "@mui/material/ToggleButtonGroup";

const Tableau3 = ["#4e79a7", "#f28e2c", "#e15759"];

const chartsParams = {
  margin: { bottom: 20, left: 25, right: 5 },
  height: 300
};
export default function BasicColor() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("#4e79a7");

  const handleChange = (event, nextColor) => {
    setColor(nextColor);
  };

  return (
    <Stack
      direction="column"
      spacing={2}
      alignItems="center"
      sx={{ width: "100%" }}
    >
      <LineChart
        sx={{
          //This sx does nothing
          "& .MuiXAxis-root line": {
            stroke: "blue" // Change the color of the x-axis line
          },
          "& .MuiYAxis-root line": {
            stroke: "blue" // Change the color of the y-axis line
          }
        }}
        {...chartsParams}
        series={[
          {
            data: [15, 23, 18, 19, 13],
            label: "example",
            color
          }
        ]}
      />
      <ToggleButtonGroup
        // orientation="vertical"
        value={color}
        exclusive
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {Tableau3.map((value) => (
          <ToggleButton key={value} value={value} sx={{ p: 1 }}>
            <div
              style={{
                width: 15,
                height: 15,
                backgroundColor: value,
                display: "inline-block"
              }}
            />
          </ToggleButton>
        ))}
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a code sandbox with the default code written inside it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/k3z7k2?file=/Demo.tsx

Answer (score 5):

MUI X relies on SVG for rendering and `sx` props to modify the styling of charts:
Here is an example of styling X Y axis (left & bottom),tickLabels : colors & width:

```
sx={{
    //change left yAxis label styles
   "& .MuiChartsAxis-left .MuiChartsAxis-tickLabel":{
    strokeWidth:"0.4",
    fill:"#ff0000"
   },
   // change all labels fontFamily shown on both xAxis and yAxis
   "& .MuiChartsAxis-tickContainer .MuiChartsAxis-tickLabel":{
       fontFamily: "Roboto",
    },
    // change bottom label styles
    "& .MuiChartsAxis-bottom .MuiChartsAxis-tickLabel":{
        strokeWidth:"0.5",
        fill:"#0000FF"
     },
      // bottomAxis Line Styles
     "& .MuiChartsAxis-bottom .MuiChartsAxis-line":{
      stroke:"#0000FF",
      strokeWidth:0.4
     },
     // leftAxis Line Styles
     "& .MuiChartsAxis-left .MuiChartsAxis-line":{
      stroke:"#00000FF",
      strokeWidth:0.4
     }
  }}
```

You can find other classes in documentation : https://mui.com/x/api/charts/charts-axis/#css
Or from inspecting DOM Tree.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `.MuiXAxis-root` is not a CSS class used. You could use

`.MuiChartsAxis-root`, `.MuiChartsAxis-directionX`, or  `.MuiChartsAxis-bottom` for the x axis